# SQL Query :Filter help needed

Tags: sql, count, normalization

I have 2 tables.One is OrderMaster and second is OrderDetails.Both are connected via OrderId

Order table fields : OrderId(Primary Key),Total,OrderDate

OrderDetail fields : OrderDetailId,ItemId,SupplierId,Amount,OrderId (ForiegnKey)

One order can have multiple orderdetail records which can be from various suppliers

Now i want to get Orders with only a purticular SupplierId value(Ex : 4) and the count (distinct supplierid)=2 .All Orders which have this supplier Id should not be included in the result set as some of it may  having other suppliers too.The expected output is
  OrderId, Sum*Amount for those records which belongs to a particular supplier (Only this supplier in the order)

EDIT : i think Count(supplierId)=1 should be a part of the query.

Comment: You will have to clear this up a bit. Do you want only orders that are fully supplier # 4? Or only the total for suppliers even if the supplier for a particular order might include other suppliers?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select OrderId, Sum(Amount) 
from OrderDetail 
where SupplierId = 4 
group by OrderId
```

Comment: @klausbyskov: If you click on the vote total, it splits in two numbers, one for up and oen for down votes.  For me it says "1|0" so you don't have any downvotes?

Comment: If Shyju is wanting orders that only have details from said supplier, that query won't work; it won't exclude orders that have details from other suppliers as well as SupplierId #4.

Comment: @Andomar the person must have changed it. there was a down vote earlier, believe me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to select orders with only one particular supplier.  The `where` clause looks for details for that supplier, and filters out orders with mixed suppliers. The Total is then calculated for each detail row.

```
select     od.OrderId
,          sum(od.Sum * od.Amount) as Total
from       OrderDetails od
where      od.SupplierId = 4
and        not exists (
           select   *
           from     OrderDetails od2
           where    od2.OrderId = od.OrderId
           and      od2.SupplierId <> od.SupplierId
           )
group by   od.OrderId
```

I'm not sure the `sum` is correct; here it's multiplying the `Sum` column with the `Amount` column.  If you just need amount, you could write it like:

```
,          sum(od.Amount) as Total
```

Joining on OrderMaster is not required, since we can grab the OrderId from the details table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
DECLARE @Supl INT

SELECT @Supl = 4

SELECT  om.OrderID,
        SUM(Amount) TotalForSupplier
FROm    OrderMaster om INNER JOIN
        OrderDetails od ON om.OrderID = od.OrderID
WHERE   od.SupplierId = @Supl
GROUP BY om.OrderID
```

This will get you the totals for a given supplier accross orders.

This should probable include a price field,

SUM(Amount * Price)

If you wish to only have the *OrderID* and *Total* you can exclude the inner join

```
SELECT  od.OrderID,
    SUM(od.Amount) TotalForSupplier
FROm    OrderDetails od
WHERE   od.SupplierId = @Supl
GROUP BY od.OrderID
```

Comment: Excuse me, but why do you need the join?

Comment: The op might want to include detail from the *OrderMaster* such as the *OrderDate*